# Bring templated base class conversion operator into derived scope

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class that defines a constrained templated conversion operator

```
struct base {
    template <typename C, std::enable_if_t<some_constraints<C>, int> = 0>
    operator C() const;
};
```

I also have a derived class that implements another conversion operator with different constraints:

```
struct derived : base {
    template <typename P, std::enable_if_t<different_constraints<P>, int> = 0>
    operator P() const;
};
```

Unfortunately, the declaration in the derived class hides the operator in the base class. I would like to bring the base operator into the derived scope, but the "obvious" syntax

```
template <typename C>
using base::operator C;
```

doesn't work (the compiler seems to try to parse it as an alias template declaration).

Does anyone know of the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: you need to derive `public` or it will not be visible in the derived class: `struct derived : public base {...`

Comment: @Aganju No you don't.  `struct` has `public` access by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is not possible. and even if it was, your derived operator would hide base one as template argument is not part according to [namespace.udecl#15.sentence-1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#15.sentence-1):

> When a using-declarator brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting)

Unfortunately, template parameter doesn't count and both conversion `operator` has empty parameter-type-list, are `const` and no ref-qualifier.

Comment: That quote seems to settle it, I agree that it doesn't seem possible to unhide the base class operator (or hidden base-class member function templates in general, apparently). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Following trick requires GNU g++, with C++14.

If `some_constraints` and `different_constraints` are mutually exclusive, you can add `using base::operator auto;` in `derived` class to make all the conversion operators of `base` available.

Example:

```
struct Base {
protected:
    // conversion to pointer types (protected).
    template<typename T, typename= typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type>
    operator T() const;
};

struct Derived : public Base{
    // Make all Base conversion operators public.
    using Base::operator auto;

    // conversion to default constructible & non-pointer types.
    // added an extra typename=void to distinguish from Base template operator.
    template<typename T, typename= typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type,typename=void>
    operator T() const;
};
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/34gbs)

Comment: This is a great solution for GCC, but unfortunately it doesn't work with Clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PuJmLIIMs1GJN8CB

Comment: @TristanBrindle Answer updated to mention it is not portable. I have no idea if the C++ standard allows this syntax, or if g++ is just being flexible.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a similar effect, you could move the constraints inside the operator and call the base conversion operator if the constraints are not satisfied:

```cpp
struct base {
    template <typename C, std::enable_if_t<some_constraints<C>, int> = 0>
    operator C() const;
};

struct derived : base {
    template <typename P>
    operator P() const {
        if constexpr (different_constraints<P>) {
            // Overridden operator
        } else {
            return base::operator P();
        }
    }
};
```

Or equivalently have one regular `std::enable_if_t<different_constraints<P>, int> = 0` conversion operator and another `std::enable_if_t<!different_constraints<P>, int> = 0`  that calls the base conversion operator.

Comment: The idea is good, but you would need to check both conditions, otherwise traits like std::is_convertible would likely cause compilation errors by instantiating that template...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can "solve" this issue by using a conversion constructor - but this is not always possible (like converting to pointer T).